# What is the cause of the "path/file access error" error

Tags: excel, vba

The hard part of this error is that it does not occur all the time, but I think it is due to the userforms. The program works as it should most of the time, but eventually `Error 1` pops out. After `Error 1` pops out, when I attempt to double click any other userform module in the VBE, `Error 2` would pop out. I believe `Error 1` occurs because the program is unable to access the user forms as shown by `Error 2.` When we attempt to save the Excel file after the error occurs, the excel file would crash. I also noticed that the errors start after a certain amount of time (even when idling and alt+tabbed) after not doing anything for example, 20 minutes, then try to select a userform, it will error (note: I do not have any time activated code for sure). Similar problems were noted in these URLs but no solutions: [Similar problem](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?500971-RESOLVED-Path-File-Access-Error) and [Similar problem 2](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-34443.html). After checking google, this problem have been plaguing people for more than 10 years already. Has no one ever figured out the cause for theirs? Any help would really be much appreciated for other people as well. Update: Errors occur in Excel 2007 (both computers at the office). I've never seen the error occur to my yet at home with my Excel 2016.

The images of the errors and debugging are shown below:

Error 1:

[image: Error 1]

Error 2:

[image: Error 2]

After Error 1 occurs and try to save the file crash:
[image: Crash]

Debug (all userforms will stop working):

[image: Debug in VBE 2]

Comment: We need the code of your entire sub you are running. It doesn't really help us, if you just show it crashed on an user-defined object.

Comment: @Rawrplus all the userforms crash after any one of the userforms give that error. I'll post the modules here

Comment: Add error handling (`on error goto` ...) in all your Subs and you will have a clear view on where it crashes. No one can really answer your question in the actual state.

Comment: Doesn't the errors returned by the VBE have any meaning at all though? I do not understand the depth of VBA enough to know what is happening inside

Comment: If you add error handling you will know exactly on which line of code (instruction) the error occur. Which is the most important thing to know to solve your issue.

Comment: Isn't that the similar to running through the code using F8? Also if it highlighted in yellow when the error occurs, won't `on error goto` be the same? Also I do believe this due to an old excel version since i've never encountered it while I was using the program on my main computer with an Excel 2016. I'll test it later.

Comment: You've shown us the error is caused by `VoucherEntry.Show` - perhaps you're not aware, but there is likely to be an event triggered by `.Show`ing the userform `VoucherEntry` - it's probably called `UserForm_Initialize` and to access it you'll need to right click on the Userform and select View Code. You can see this yourself if you F8 through the code. When the error finally occurs the VBEditor will return to the Subroutine that called the `.Show`. So - to find your error, we'd need to see *all of the code* called by it.

Comment: It is considered bad practice to use the default instance of a userform when showing. Instead you should use a discrete instance of the userform, eg. `with new VoucherEntry` `.show` `End With`. You can read more about why [here](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/)

Comment: @CLR All the code shown under the `UserForm_Initialize` event of my `VoucherEntry` form?

Comment: @TaylorScott Thanks for the reference

Comment: That's likely to be where the actual error is, @MarcSantos - or, if that calls other subroutines or functions, in one of those.

Comment: @CLR okay I will try running my program in a more later version of Excel first instead of the Excel 2007's. If it resolves by itself I will not step through the code anymore. Because 2007 is already obsolete and no point in trying to work around it, but if it still crashes in 2016 then i'll update on this

Comment: Try to remove `VoucherEntry` form from your project (do not forget to export it before you do that) and save your Excel file. Then, change an extension for `VoucherEntry` file to `*.txt`, open Excel file again and import that form from text file. If it helps, reply me.

Comment: Just curious, are there any ComboBox/Controls with RowSource pointed to a Table (ListObject)? If so, clear it and add the RowSource at UserForm_Initialize.

Comment: @MarcSantos when you are working at the office on Excel 2007, is your file working from the PC's local drive, or from a network drive? At home, I'm assuming you're only ever working from the PC's local drive, am I correct?

Comment: @girlvsdata Yes that is correct

Comment: @PatricK I added my codes. I do not have a `RowSource` pointed to a table in the properties window of the combo box, however I have this code in the UserForm_Initialize event: `ListBox6.RowSource = "Table!A2:D" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets("Table").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, Worksheets("Table").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`

Comment: I am really not experiencing this problem when i'm running it at Excel 2016. I don't know why the mods removed such valuable information from the answers. Despite `AutoRecover` or anything. It's probably a older version related error

Comment: A lot of work needed to debug your partial code, and lots doesn't make sense (e.g. `Trim(Len(tbxNewPayee.Text)) = 0` should be `Len(Trim(tbxNewPayee.Text)) = 0`). Since you are using ListObjects on worksheets, you can simplify many steps. Also use `Option Explicit` for coding. Can you step through your code and note where is crash?

Comment: Oh you're right about that no wonder some textboxes such as the date are sometimes working a bit weird, but not much loss in functionality. Right i'll be using `Option Explicit` didn't expect the program to be large. Can you give an example of how I can simplify because i'm using ListObjects? I'm actually thinking if it's practical to use tables (List Objects) even with mainly VBA or better without tables. Do you suggest I do? Hold on i'll step through it after the error pops out. I timed it to be 10 minutes when the `AutoRecover` procs as @girlvsdata mentioned.

Comment: @PatricK I cannot run through my code after the error appears. No matter where in the module I try to step through, I get a `Run-time error 75 - Could not find specified object` all userforms will not work and it will crash when I try to double click the userform.

Comment: I have similar issue to import a file from share drive "P" to an application on winSVR 2012, but it only works when I add my self into the server's admin group

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both errors you are having, "Path/File access error" and "Run Time Error 75" are errors accessing the filepath, and they are likely being caused by the AutoRecover feature of Excel.

When you are leaving your Excel file for 20 minutes or so, the time limit for AutoRecover is reached. AutoRecover will then attempt to save AutoRecover information, in the case of your home computer it will be saving that to the Local drive, and at the office it will be saving to the network.

> When an Excel file is open and AutoRecover is turned on, AutoRecover does not save the file until the first change is made to the file, the AutoRecover save time interval passes, and Excel has been idle for some time (the default is 30 seconds). (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/289273/description-of-the-autorecover-functions-in-excel)

What is likely happening is a connection with your network is being interrupted, causing the AutoRecover to fail, which you won't see until the 'ActivateWorkbook' event is triggered (which will show your userform, then crash).

(You can check your time limit for AutoRecover in Options>Save>Save Workbooks)
[image: Save Options Image]

You might be able to work around the error by:

- saving the file to your local drive while you are at the office, or
- disabling AutoRecover for the workbook
- increasing the amount of time before the AutoRecover is triggered.

This user also found their errors were resolved by removing and repairing corrupt updates: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/438888-intermittent-run-time-error-75-loading-form.html

Comment: Can you only disable `AutoRecover` in 1 workbook though? It's impractical to disable for all. Also, the file is located at the desktop isn't that part of the main local drive?

Comment: @MarcSantos If you open that option menu I mentioned in my answer, a little further down on the same page there is a checkbox "Disable AutoRecover for this workbook only." Depending on your workplace, the desktop could also be a network drive (my workplace has done this in the past), but usually it is on the local drive.

Comment: My desktop is in local disk C for the office computers. Does this invalidate the solution? Perhaps I can try the `AutoRecover` disabling for the workbook

Comment: @MarcSantos it does not invalidate the solution, it just means that something else is interrupting the AutoRecover. It may be a regular system backup that occurs in your office, or a corrupt update file. I'd still recommend trying the file with AutoRecover disabled, and seeing if that helps.

Comment: Will do. Thanks going to the office to try it out now before I update our excel versions to more recent ones if all else fails

Comment: the error did appear on around the 11 minute mark rather than the 10 minute mark. I guess it has something to do with the `AutoRecover` as you mentioned.

Comment: I'll try to wait another 10 minutes after restarting my file. If it crashes again very close to that time i'll disable the `AutoRecover` then if it works. Then i'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: 2nd time around took 15 minutes after restarting my file. Well i'll just try disabling it and see

Comment: Yep disabling the `AutoRecover` did the job. It also makes sense because the error would only appear after a time delay, but I do not have any time activated codes. I'll test a bit more before awarding the bounty to make sure it really did fix it. But 30 minutes in, still haven't crashed. It's a bug of Excel 2007 and earlier, the mods removed it from the answers.

Comment: @MarcSantos great news, happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

**you can just save the current workbook with this:**

```
ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

**or disabling auto recover with code**

```
Application.Autorecover.Enable = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when using the FileCopy(Source, Destination) function. I resolved it by saving a copy of the source file under a different name